# how I can call a function twig extension?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need to call a function in  vendor (twig) from bundle in src .
so I need to create function in twing extension ?

if yes !!

how I can do this

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Could you give an example?

Comment: Welcome to the jungle of non-readers of the StackOverflow's lineguides like: [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a twig extension.

There is [nice and easy tutorial in Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html#create-the-extension-class).

Comment: but I can't  call this fonction in vendor !!!

Comment: Vendor is for composer, you shall not edit it. What's your exact use case? Could you provide some code if possible?